# HUnit not importing on Mac

Tags: macos, haskell, ghc, hunit

On a fresh install of Haskell Platform for Max OSX, the following code fails on `import Test.HUnit` when run using the `runghc` interpreter.

```
{--
 - Save this file as Main.hs and run with % runghc Main.hs
 -}

module Main where

import Test.HUnit

derp = test [ "a silly test" ~: 'a' ~=? 'a' ]
tests = TestList [ derp ]

main::IO()
main = (runTestTT tests) >>= (\x -> putStrLn $ show x)
```

However, when using ghci, doing a simple `import Test.HUnit` works just fine.

How can I resolve this discrepancy between `ghc` from the command line and the `ghci` REPL?

Comment: What is exact error message? Also try add `-v` option and post output

Comment: Works for me.  What do you get when you run `ghc-pkg check`?

Comment: The error was `Main.hs:3:8:Could not find module 'Test.HUnit'`, but attempting again today it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot the machine. Not sure whether it's paths not containing the right directories or something else, but a fresh start after install seems to have resolved it.